# Ignore a Field in a type annotation

Tags: python, type-hinting, pydantic

If I have a pydantic class like:

```
from typing import Annotated, get_origin
from pydantic import BaseModel

class IgnorableBaseModel(BaseModel):
    _ignored: ClassVar[dict[str, Any]] = {}

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """do something with _ignored, else fallback to default"""

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs) -> None:
        del_keys = []
        for key, annotation in cls.__annotations__.items():
            if key.startswith("_"):  # exclude protected/private attributes
                continue
            if get_origin(annotation) is Annotated:
                if get_args(annotation)[1] == "ignore me"
                    cls._ignored[key] = cls.__annotations__[key]
                    del_keys.append(key)
        for key in del_keys:
            del cls.__annotations__[key]

class MyClass(IgnorableBaseModel):
    name: Annotated[str, "ignore me"]   # ignore this
    x: int
```

I am using this name for a variable that is defined during the `__init__` and accessed via `__getattr__` so I can't set a value for it.  Is there a way to tell mypy to ignore this, or do I need to always override the init args like:

```
class MyClass(IgnorableBaseModel):
    name: Annotated[str, "ignore me"]
    x: int

    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

It'd be great if there was an annotation I could add that would inform mypy that this variable was not needed during the init.

"ignore me" is used here to indicate that I don't want to see the error:

```
Missing named argument "name" for "MyClass"Mypycall-arg
```

To provide some background, I'm trying to make a python DSL and so it helps to be able to have some attributes type hinted, but not actually require values.

Comment: The field definitions look inconsistent to me. What does ignore mean? Is the field optional or is it private? Or should it be ignored for serialization?

Comment: If `name` is an attribute defined inside `__init__`, why isn't it in your explicitly defined `__init__`. If it's *not* an attribute, what exactly does `__init__` do with it?

Comment: If you were talking about Python's native dataclasses, I would think you are looking for either an `InitVar` or a field defined with `field(init=False, ...)`, but it's not clear which one.

Comment: apologies for the lack of clarity, I'll make some clarifications

Comment: Are you using the [Pydantic mypy plugin](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/integrations/mypy/)? Many of Pydantic-specific features won't work with mypy without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `name` to be defined by `__init__` without having to pass its value as an argument, use the `init` argument to `Field`.

```py
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    name: Annotated[str, Field(init=False)]
    x: int
```

This can also be written as

```py
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(init=False)
    x: int
```

Now the autogenerated `__init__` method will only expect an argument for `x`, and it will be up to use to ensure the `name` attribute on an instance of `MyClass` gets defined. (This could be by using a default value, or a default factory, or an explicitly defined `__init__` method, or some other technique that Pydantic provides.)

Comment: mypy is still complaining:
Missing named argument "name" for "MyClass" if you do the top version.  I believe this is documented as a mypy bug

Comment: also, it looks like the second example will fail if you run MyClass(x=3)

Comment: approving, this was very helpful but i think it could be improved.  I believe you want to use the dataclass `field`

Comment: I know with `dataclasses.dataclass`, you are supposed to use the factory function `field` instead of instantiating `dataclasses.Field` directly. Pydantic refers to `pydantic.Field` and `dataclasses.field` as if they are separate things (implying that `pydantic.Field` is not the same as `dataclasses.Field`. You've piqued my interest, so I'll look deeper.

Comment: Ok, yes, `pydantic.Field` is (despite the capitalization) an actual function, not a class, which is analogous to `dataclasses.field`, but with more Pydantic-specific customization available (though I'm using anything Pydantic-specific in this answer).

Comment: it looks like that was added to pydantic recently: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/commit/a2a4281a6eeb3cf6e8296600ff13ac25815ccc20